# accessing specific elements of arrays in a foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays

I apologize if this is a very simple question - I've read through tons of posts here, but my question is syntactically very hard to *search* for, so I haven't found an answer yet.

I have a json array that's output from a company's API:

```
[Result] => Array
        (
            [cData] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [Reqa] => ABCD
                            [Reqb] => 
                            [Reqc] => Plus
                            [dto] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [ComID] => 43292392                                            
                                            [Comment] => Dave
                                        )

                                    [1] => Array
                                        (
                                            [ComID] => 43292392                                            
                                            [Comment] => Bob
                                        )

                                )

                            [XREFSearchOperation] => Exact
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [Reqa] => BCDE
                            [Reqb] => 
                            [Reqc] => A
                            [dto] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [ComID] => 19331186                                            
                                            [Comment] => Mike
                                        )

                                    [1] => Array
                                        (
                                            [ComID] => 19331186
                                            [Comment] => Roger
                                        )

                                )

                            [XREFSearchOperation] => Starts With
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [Reqa] => QQDT
                            [Reqb] => 
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

and I'm trying to access the `[ComID]` and `[Comment]` elements, if they exist, inside of a foreach loop and assign it to the variable `$y`

So far I have:

```
foreach ($json['Result']['cData']['dto'] as $i) {
 $y = "{$i['ComID']}|{$i['Comment']}";
}
```

but this gives me zero results.  I understand **WHY**, because in between `['cData']` and `['dto']` are `[0]`, `[1]`, `[2]` `etc..` elements, and I don't know how to add a qualifier for *those* into the loop.

## Update

This code works for most of the json response:

```
foreach ($json['Result']['cData'] as $i) {
    if(array_key_exists('dto', $i)) {
      foreach ($i['dto'] as $j) {
 $y = "{$j['ComID']}|{$j['Comment']}";
      } else {
        }      
    }
```

However - I'm having one more small issue.  If there are multiple [dto] responses, you'll have `[dto][0][ComID]` then `[dto][1][ComID]` and `[dto][2][ComID]`, (like in the example above,) but if there's only ONE response, you'll have `[dto][ComID]` as there's no need for that middle array.

I tried writing `if(array_key_exists('dto[0]'` to execute one, then an else statement in the event `dto[0]` doesn't exist, but that didn't work.  I need a way of NOT executing a `foreach` loop if there is no array underneath it to `"foreachicize"`.  Is there an if/else statement I can write to accommodate this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably need a nested `foreach`:

```
foreach ($json['Result']['cData'] as $i) {
    foreach($i['dto'] as $j) {
        $y[] = "{$j['ComID']}|{$j['Comment']}"; //need an array here
    }
}
```

For the update to the question.  Check if `$i['dto'][0]` exists:

```
foreach ($json['Result']['cData'] as $i) {
    if(isset($i['dto'][0]))) {
        foreach($i['dto'] as $j) {
            $y[] = "{$j['ComID']}|{$j['Comment']}";
        }
    } else {
        $y[] = "{$j['ComID']}|{$j['Comment']}";
    }
}
```

There might be a better way but I'm headed out.

Comment: Both this and the other answer are good.  Are there any benefits to using a method like this to the other answer posted?

Comment: Are you able to have a look at my updated question?  There's one more slight problem I didn't foresee in my original question....

Answer (score 0):

Another approach:

```
foreach($json['Result']['cData'] as $cData) 
{
    foreach($cData['dto'] as $dto) 
    {
        if(array_key_exists('ComID', $dto) && array_key_exists('Comment', $dto))
        {
            $y = "{$dto['ComID']}|{$dto['Comment']}";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ooo, I really like this one too.

Comment: @AbraCadaver Thanks, I missed the variable name, have edited that now

Comment: Thank you for this @henrik.  Your `if(array_key_exists` code actually came in very useful, as not each instance of this was formatted the same way.  Using this, in conjunction with the answer below, I was able to write the loop to get back the answer I wanted.